# How to refer to columns containing f-strings in a Pyspark function?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, f-string

I am writing a function for a Spark DF that performs operations on columns and gives them a suffix, such that I can run the function twice on two different suffixes and join them later.

I am having a *time* of figuring out the best way to refer to them however in this particular bit of code and was wondering what I am missing?

```
def calc_date(sdf, suffix):
    final_sdf = (
        sdf.withColumn(
            f"lowest_days{suffix}",
            f"sdf.list_of_days_{suffix}"[0],
        )
        .withColumn(
            f"earliest_date_{suffix}",
            f"sdf.list_of_dates_{suffix}"[0],
        )
        .withColumn(
            f"actual_date_{suffix}",
            spark_fns.expr(
                f"date_sub(earliest_date_{suffix}, lowest_days{suffix})"
            ),
        )
    )
```

Here I am trying to pull the first value from two lists (`list_of_days` and `list_of_dates`) and perform a date calculation to create a new variable (`actual_date`).

I would like to do this in a function so that I don't have to do the same set of operations twice (or more) depending on the number of suffixes I have?

But the f-strings give an error `col should be Column`.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the second argument with a col().

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

def calc_date(sdf, suffix):
    final_sdf = (
        sdf.withColumn(
            f"lowest_days{suffix}",
            col(f"list_of_days_{suffix}")[0],
        )
        .withColumn(
            f"earliest_date_{suffix}",
            col(f"list_of_dates_{suffix}")[0],
        )
    )
```

Comment: hmm unfortunately I now get an error `cannot resolve sdf.list_of_days_suffix given in put columns list_of_days_suffix`

Comment: If my answer was helpful, an upvote would be appreciated!